# get props from children component through hoc

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which is going through an hoc, but i want to get some props of this component inside the hoc. All works fine but i can not find out how to get the props out of this child component into the hoc.

here is the component which is going through the hoc, and that is this 'getAction' props i want to extract in the hoc

```
    class ProjectPage2 extends Component {
            
            
        render() {
                return (
                                <Project2 getAction="getAction"/>
                );  
        };  
};

export default PageHandler(ProjectPage2)
```

here is the hoc component (imported as PageHandler in the ProjectPage2)

```
    export default (ChildComponent) => {
        class ComposedComponent extends Component {
                               
                               
                render() {     
                        // here i want to get the 'getAction' props, which is inside this ChildComponent
                        // because i need to use it into this hoc logic
                        return <ChildComponent {...this.props} />;   
             
                }   
        }   
          
        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
                return {       
                        comments: state.project2        
                }
        };
        
        const loadData = (store) => {   
                return store.dispatch(getProject2());
        };
          
        return {               
                loadData,      
                component: connect(mapStateToProps, { getProject2 })(ComposedComponent)
    
        }
};
```

if some one have an idea it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer. But it s not what i was looking for. I wanted to get into the HOC some children component's props passing through. But i finally get the idea which solved it. In fact it s so simple......

i wanted to pass the "getAction" string into the HOC. But i didn t find any solution to extract it (from the passing through component) there.
The solution is simply to pass it into the  export default

```
class ProjectPage2 extends Component {
            
            
        render() {
                return (
                                // i was trying to use the component props
                               // <Project2 getAction="getAction"/>
                               // but no need
                               <Project2 />
                );  
        };  
};
// pass it into the fonction fix it
export default PageHandler(ProjectPage2, "getAction")
```

then get it in the HOC

```
 export default (ChildComponent, varAction) => {
        class ComposedComponent extends Component {
                          console.log(varAction) // return getAction
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're very close already. It looks to me like you want the final result to be something like:

```
<Project2 getAction="getAction" comments={...} />
```

But what ends up getting rendered is just:

```
<Project2 getAction="getAction" />
```

See, the custom props of your HOC are passed to your child component via the child's props. You aren't using those, so the child just completely ignores the HOC. You can fix this with:

```
class ProjectPage2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Project2 getAction="getAction" {...this.props} />
        );  
    };  
}
```